# ImportError Cannot import name - nonspecific

Tags: python, pip, python-import, software-distribution, python-packaging

I have made python package from 
https://github.com/raamana/pyradigm
and uploaded it to `pip` using the following commands (after following the instructions on pypi, etc):

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload dist/*
```

In theory, now one should be able to do

```
pip install pyradigm
```

(which I can confirm works) and then do the following in a Python file:

```
from pyradigm import MLDataset
```

to use the class `MLDataset` from `pyradigm`

Unfortunately it's not the case, as Python is throwing the following `ImportError` which is fairly non-specific:

```
In [1]: from pyradigm import MLDataset
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4ad7330da13e> in <module>()
----> 1 from pyradigm import MLDataset

ImportError: cannot import name MLDataset
```

I can confirm that

1. I was able to install pyradigm via pip on a new system
2. both pip and python are able to find the package (installed in site-packages), as they auto-fill both the module name (`pyradigm` and class name `MLDataset`).

The setup.py in pyradigm is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Utility function to read the README file.
def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(name='pyradigm',
      version='0.1.1.2',
      description='Python-based data structure to improve handling of datasets in machine learning workflows',
      long_description=read('README.md'),
      keywords='machine learning, test dataset, python, workflow, provenance, data structure',
      author='Pradeep Reddy Raamana',
      url='https://github.com/raamana/pyradigm',
      packages=find_packages(exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]), # packages=['pyradigm'],
      install_requires=['numpy', 'setuptools'],
     )
```

The package has only 3 files:

```
__init__.py      pyradigm.py      test_pyradigm.py
```

with the `__init__.py` containing the only a single line:

```
__all__ = [ 'pyradigm', 'MLDataset' ]
```

Any help in understanding in this error, and ways to fix it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried `pip install pyradigm --upgrade?`
Do you have on your computer another version of python?

Comment: I get the following:

`$ 09:04:40 miner ~ >>  pip install --upgrade pyradigm
Requirement already up-to-date: pyradigm in ./anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in 
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in 
Requirement already up-to-date: packaging>=16.8 in 
Requirement already up-to-date: appdirs>=1.4.0 in 
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.6.0 in
Requirement already up-to-date: pyparsing in `

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: pyradigm in ./anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: for all of numpy
setuptools
packaging>=16.8
appdirs>=1.4.0
six>=1.6.0
pyparsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a `pyradigm` module inside a `pyradigm` package.

I've installed the package in a `virtualenv` using `pip install pyradigm` and successfully imported `MLDataset` with

```
from pyradigm.pyradigm import MLDataset
```

If you want to import as

```
from pyradigm import MLDataset
```

update your `__init__.py` to

```
from pyradigm import MLDataset
```

Comment: thanks @dm295. Is there a way I can improve my organization of the package so it is intuitive to other people?

Comment: @PradeepReddyRaamana since you have followed instructions on `pypi` I think it should be fine

Comment: Apparently not in naming them properly. I would like to do from pyradigm import MLDataset, even without that statement in init.. is that possible?